# Export SFC and Tailwind styles in Vue/Vite Component Library

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tailwind-css, vite

My Vue component library built with Vite is removing the CSS classes defined in the Vue SFC `<style>` definitions and keeping only the tailwind classes in the built library.  The tailwind styles are working in the downstream project, but again the SFC styles are being removed. How do I fix this?

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./lib/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
  corePlugins: {
    //preflight: false,
  },
  prefix: 'chartsjs-'
}
```

vite.config.js

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

const path = require('path')
const { defineConfig } = require('vite')
const vue = require("@vitejs/plugin-vue");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib/index.ts'),
      name: 'chartsjs',
      fileName: (format) => `chartsjs.${format}.js`
    }
  },
  assetsInclude: ['**/*.typeface.json'],
  rollupOptions: {
    // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
    // into your library
    external: ["vue"],
    output: {
      // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
      // for externalized deps
      globals: {
        vue: "Vue",
      },
    },
    outDir: "dist",
    declaration: true, // ts deefintions
  },
  // exclude: ["src/App.vue", "src/main.ts"],
});
```

Comment: It's probably nothing related to the issue, but, in vite.config.js you'e using so called ESModule syntax to import `import ... from ...;` and CommonJS syntax to export `module.exports=...`